# routing paramenter returns null when only supplying first paramenter in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

My issue is that I made a Map Route in MVC which takes three parameters.  When I supply all three or just two, the parameters are passed from the URL to my controller.  However, when I only supply the first parameter, it is not passed and returns null.  Not sure what causes this behavior.

Route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Details",                                              // Route name
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",                           // URL with parameters
            defaults: new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
         );
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Map(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {

        StoreMap makeMap = new StoreMap();
        var storemap = makeMap.makeStoreMap(param1, param2, param3);
        var model = storemap;
        return View(model);
    }
```

string param1 returns null when I navigate to:

/StoreMap/Map/PARAM1NAME

but it doesn't return null when I navigate to:

/StoreMap/Map/PARAM1NAME/PARAM2NAME

Comment: Perhaps Parameter isn't the right term.  Maybe it is an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the default route is interfering. I believe the default route defined in the project template looks like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Your URL with only one parameter matches this pattern, but since you don't have an `id` parameter in your method signature, the value doesn't get populated into any of your parameters.

You could try altering your "Details" route to hard-code the controller to be "Details", as shown below, and move it so that it comes before the default route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Details",                                              // Route name
        url: "Details/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",                           // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", param1 = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
     );


    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Alternatively, try renaming the first parameter in your route and your method signature to `id`.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Details",                                              // Route name
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{param2}/{param3}",                           // URL with parameters
        defaults: new { controller = "Details", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, param2 = UrlParameter.Optional, param3 = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
     );


public ActionResult Map(string id, string param2, string param3)
{

    StoreMap makeMap = new StoreMap();
    var storemap = makeMap.makeStoreMap(id, param2, param3);
    var model = storemap;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you.  This was the problem.  I actually quickly solved it by placing the default router below the router I created.  Your answer helped me better understand MVC.